# Square integrability

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Given a function $g(y)=\int_y^{\infty}f(x) dx$ and given that I know that for $y\rightarrow-\infty$ the function $g(y)\rightarrow C$, where C is a constant, why is the last condition implying that the function $g(y)$ is not square integrable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $C\ne 0$, say $C>0$, then for some $x_0\in\mathbb R$, we shall have
$$
x \le x_0\quad\Longrightarrow\quad g(x)>\frac{C}{2}.
$$
Hence
$$
\int_{\mathbb R}g^2(y)\,dy\ge\int_{x_0-M}^{x_0}g^2(y)\,dy\ge \frac{MC^2}{4},
$$
and as the right-hand side can be as large as we please, for sufficiently large $M$, then $\int_{\mathbb R}g^2(y)\,dy$ can not be bounded.

Comment: Sorry, why is $\int_x^{\infty}f(s)ds>\frac{c}{2}$?

Comment: You say that $\lim_{y\to -\infty}g(y)=C$. Then $g(y)>C/2$, for $y$ sufficiently small.

Comment: Ok, I got it. One last thing, is this part of some rule regarding square integrable functions? I mean without going through the explanation above can we always say that when the limit of a function is $>0$ the function will not be square integrable? It seems that your proof would imply that for the case of $g(x)$ increasing.

Comment: Yes, if $g$ is increasing and positive, it is not square integrable. In general, square integrable functions tend to zero, as $|x|\to\infty$, although this does not suffice.